# My full react app folder hosted on Vercel is shown on web inspector. Is there a way to hide it?

Tags: reactjs, security, vercel

I have a React project that I hosted on Vercel. When anyone navigates the website's domain via the web inspector, they can view the whole folder and files. This is obviously a risk. How can I hide the folders?

Comment: Do you mean that the source folder is visible or the final files that user downloads anyway when visiting your website?

Comment: Hello @Konrad. Yes, on the web inspector, when you click 'By Path', then click the 'Scripts' folder, there is a build file 'main.29470289.js' which has the 'folder disclosure triangle' or the icon. It displays all the subfolders and files of my project when expanded. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to hide the code from the developer tools. It's a simple process as illustrated here:
https://dev.to/myogeshchavan97/how-to-hide-your-react-source-code-from-getting-displayed-in-chrome-dev-tools-when-deployed-to-production-41j7

Comment: This doesn't make anything any more secure, though, just a little easier since people don't have to deobfuscate your code by hand.

Comment: Yes. But at least it's hard to deobfuscate the minified code. Personal details such as Stripe or other Payment Gateways are somehow safer in the minified code. @AKX

Comment: No, they're absolutely not safe. You must not have any secret values in your frontend code. (Stripe has a specific separate "publishable key" expressly for this purpose, and so on.)